# Styling a code block with CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I'm writing a tutorial for my blog, and I'm using `[code][/code]` tags around the text I want to be displayed as code. I've tried replacing `[code]` with `<code>`, `<pre>` or `<div class="code-block">`

However, with `<code></code>` if I indent some lines with spaces the spaces don't show up, so it's not as easy to read. For example

```
<div id="example1">
code which I would like indented
</div>

<div id="more-code1">
more code
</div>
```

With `<pre></pre>` the spaces do show up okay, but it looks like this

```
<div id="example2">

code which I would like indented

</div>



<div id="more-code2">
more code
</div>
```

If I do `<div class="code-block"></div>` it looks the same as using `code`

It could be to do with how I display the posts, so here's my PHP code

```
<div class="box-content">
    <p><?php echo bbconvert(nl2br(htmlentities($post['content'], ENT_QUOTES))); ?></p>
</div>
```

`bbconvert()` is a simple function that replaces `[list]` with `<ul>` or `[row]` with `<li>`

Answer (score 7):

Have you taken a look at [Google Code Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)?

I've used it for countless code displays and tutorials.
If not, put it between `<pre></pre>` tags. This will make whitespace matter in the HTML, so whatever you type in the .html file will show up exactly as typed on the webpage in a monospace font

Comment: It has moved here https://github.com/googlearchive/code-prettify and is no longer supported. I guess you would like to use different libs, Monaco editor has powerful features for example.

Comment: Or highlight (https://highlightjs.org/) unfortunately both this and Markdown are (rather heavy) JS libs... no pure css

Answer (score 4):

You need to either surround the `<code>` elements with `<pre>` tags, or you need to paste on a CSS style of [`white-space: pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space). Those two things should be equivalent in most cases. The `pre` setting means that the renderer will preserve the spaces instead of collapsing them as normal, and will break lines on newlines as well.

For example, if you choose `<div class="code-block">`, then `div.code-block { white-space: pre; }` in your CSS rules should help. Or you could just go with

```
<pre><code>
code which I would like indented
</code></pre>
```

Comment: thanks, but if I use `<pre>` or `white-space: pre` then instead of being 1 line in between bits of code, there's 2 lines. I think it may be due to nl2br though. may need to work out how to skip certain parts of my code.